# How to disable the dropdown when one option is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

Following is my view code

```
    <select id ="hook_select" class="form-control" name="hook_select" >
       <option value="">---Select Hook---</option>
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($email_hooks))
                        {

                        foreach ($email_hooks as $key=>$val)
                        {
                            $select = isset($form_data["email_info"]) && $form_data["email_info"]->hook == $key ? "selected" : "";
                            echo "<option value='{$key}'{$select}>{$val['name']}</option>";
                        }
                        }
                    ?>
    </select>
```

I want to disable dropdown when any one of the option is selected using jquery.

I tried the following code

```
    $(document).on("click", "#edit_email", function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var y =$("#hook_select").val();
        $("#hook_select option[value*=" + y +".]").prop('disabled',true);


    });
```

is it possible to pass the selected value ($("#hook_select").val()) on  click function ? but i didn't get the value in variable "y".In my code when click on the edit link redirect to next page.

here the view code is (view source code)

```
    <select id ="hook_select" class="form-control" name="hook_select">
    <option value="">---Select Hook---</option>
    <option value='pre_int_panel_invitation'selected>Pre-Int Panel Invitation</option>
    <option value='volunteer_interview_digest'>Daily Digest to Volunteers about Interview Invitation</option>                   
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change in your jquery function.

html code will be :

```
     <select id ="hook_select" class="form-control" name="hook_select">
         <option value="select">---Select Hook---</option>
         <option value='pre_int_panel_invitation' selected>Pre-Int Panel Invitation</option>
         <option value='volunteer_interview_digest'>Daily Digest to Volunteers about Interview Invitation</option>                   
     </select>
```

Jquery Function will be :

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
             var y = '';
             $("#hook_select").change(function(){
                 $("#hook_select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                 y=$("#hook_select").val();
                 alert(y);
             });
         });
```